# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthPhoneService (CredentialsRepository, ?, ConfigService)

Tags: nestjs

I'm trying to use NestJS with typeorm. Whilst I've had a look at some of the other similar questions out there but this seems to be different as I am using two repos in a single service and I can't seem to see anything I've done wrong.

The Error:

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthPhoneService (CredentialsRepository, ?, ConfigService). Please make sure that the argument Repository at index [1] is available in the AuthPhoneModule context.
```

I have a service called AuthPhoneService. It takes in two repos as constructor arguments:

```js
@UseFilters(new UncaughtExceptionsFilter())
@Injectable()
export class AuthPhoneService {

    constructor(@InjectRepository(Credentials)
    private credentialsRepo: Repository<Credentials>,
        private publicKeysRepo: Repository<PublicKeys>,
        private configService: ConfigService
    ) { }
...
```

As the error suggests publicKeysRepo is having problems:

I have tried defining my module like this:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthController } from '../auth-controller';
import { AuthPhoneService } from './auth-phone.service';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Credentials } from '../credential/credentials.entity';
import { AuthVerifyController } from '../verify/auth-verify.controller';
import { PublicKeys } from './publickeys.entity';
@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Credentials]),
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([PublicKeys])
    ],
    providers: [AuthPhoneService],
    controllers: [AuthController, AuthVerifyController],

})
export class AuthPhoneModule { }
```

and like this...

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthController } from '../auth-controller';
import { AuthPhoneService } from './auth-phone.service';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Credentials } from '../credential/credentials.entity';
import { AuthVerifyController } from '../verify/auth-verify.controller';
import { PublicKeys } from './publickeys.entity';
@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Credentials,PublicKeys])
    ],
    providers: [AuthPhoneService],
    controllers: [AuthController, AuthVerifyController],

})
export class AuthPhoneModule { }
```

Neither options have worked and always produced the same error.

Comment: Missing `@InjectRepository(PublicKeys)` decorator?

Comment: yup! That's the one! Post this as an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're missing `@InjectRepository()` decorator for the `publicKeysRepo`

```js
@UseFilters(new UncaughtExceptionsFilter())
@Injectable()
export class AuthPhoneService {

    constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Credentials)
    private credentialsRepo: Repository<Credentials>,
    @InjectRepository(PublicKeys) // <-- add this
    private publicKeysRepo: Repository<PublicKeys>,
    private configService: ConfigService
    ) { }
...
```